# Regex to split email address between two characters @ and .

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am trying to use Regex to get the company name out of the email address. I am splitting the email two times. Is there a better solution for this?

```
  c = "user@company_name.com"
 (c.split("@").last).split(".").first
```

Comment: So you want the top level domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Answer to the question in the post (before it was edited)

   Judging from your code, it seems like you want to extract the top level domain (although it contradicts with the title, which does not make sense). Assuming so, this will give you the top level domain.

   ```
   "user@company_name.com"[/[^.]+\z/]
   # => "com"
   ```
2. Solution to a different problem that the OP additionally mentions in the comment to this answer

   ```
   "user@company_name.com"[/(?<=@)[^.]+/]
   # => "company_name"
   ```

Comment: I need the company_name part from this email.. thanks

Comment: One minor issue is emails with subdomain. `"user@team.department.company_name.com"[/(?<=@)[^.]+/]` will result in _department_ instead of _company_name_. If you know you have a valid email, you can use string split like this: `"user@team.department.company_name.com".split("@")[1].split(".")[-2]`. This however has another issue: What if you got this `user@schoolname.schools.county.nl` ? _County_ isn't the school/company name. Best option: Have a field to fill in so the user can choose.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution given.

```
str = "user@company_name.com"[/[^@]+(?=\.)/]
```

See [working demo](http://rubular.com/r/eX9TyvE7XY)

Answer (score 1):

This will give you company name.

```
(.*)@(\w+)\.(.*)
```